# CSS only: Replace all characters in <p> with the same character

Tags: html, css

I have a `<p class="hidden"></p>` with some text in it. I want to replace all characters in the paragraph with the same character, e.g. a question mark. Note that this is not a viable solution since it requires to specify aprioristically the length of the new string:

```
.hidden {
  text-indent: -9999px;
  line-height: 0;
}

.hidden::after {
  content: "???";
}
```

As a way of example:

```
<p>Just some text!</p>
<p class="hidden">Hello, world!</p>
```

Should be rendered:

```
Just some text! 
?????????????
```

Comment: The only way that I can see that done using pure CSS is by specifying a font that only contains question mark glyphs. Trivial to do in JavaScript though.

Comment: The only way to use `p = font-size : 0px` | `p:after = font-size : 12px`. This text will not be indexed by the search engine

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10212940/1400279

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use CSS to replace or change text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10212879/how-to-use-css-to-replace-or-change-text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea is to build your own font that contain only 1 character (the ? sign) and use it for your text.

I am not familiar with this but you can easily find a lot of tools to do it. I will simply give an example using a strange font to show you the idea:

```css
@font-face {
 font-family: "Strange";
 src: url("https://css-challenges.com/ahem/dugun.regular.otf");
}


p {
  font-size:35px;
}

.hidden {
 font-family: "Strange";
}
```

```html
<p>some text here</p>
<p class="hidden">some text here</p>
```